# Pomegranate bonsai looks ill (reddish brown leaves and leaf curl)

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, bonsai, repotting, pomegranate

[image]I live in coastal Virginia zone 7b and have had a small pomegranate bonsai for 6 years now. Unfortunately last spring it started to show signs of stress or nutritional deficiency. The leaves started coming out in spring but suffering extreme curling, but they were still green. Not wishing to remove them and leave the tree to gain strength I left it alone. News leaves would come in but most would curl.

About a month ago my area had 60-70 weather and I left the pom outside (usually it's on a North West facing windowsill that gets plenty of sunshine from noon to sunset) to gain some warmth.

However I neglected it and then allowed it to spend 2-3 days of sudden cold spells in the 20s and when I realized my error brought it in.

Signs of life for the pom came back within two weeks with buds erupting and showing new growth but some would emerge and then curl into a spindle, other buds tried to emerge and then appeared to get stunted and die.

The soil I use is a bonsai mix with great drainage but figured it might be malnourished and need some potting soil (I would water ever 2-3 weeks and allow it to dry out). Changing the soil with a 50% mix of bonsai and potting soil with a little bio-tone starter plus I repotted and left the pom to enjoy sun and air.

There are no bugs but the poms new growth continues to stunt and fail. Very few of the leaves do emerge and those that do survive seem to not curl, but it's a very few amount.

I notice some of the original leaves from its healthier days are now a reddish brown mix with dark green and seem ready to drop off.

I scratched the bark and see it still alive but fear that if the new growth continues to fail I'll lose it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

[Link to google photos of Pom](https://photos.app.goo.gl/7BzdGvMyK8vXToGw5)

Comment: Update. The Pom is looking much better and even has flowers! I've taken out quite a few but left a couple just because I haven't seen any in at least three years. I will be removing them before they start becoming fruit.

That said I really want to figure out my why leaves still curl. The majority are still curling but there are pockets where they look normal. Any help is appreciated :) **I've added  a picture of how the Pom looks like now in the original post as I couldn't figure out how to in this update comment